# In weighed random graph where the edge weight is restricted to $[0,1]$, what are the usual assumptions of edge weight distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, random-graphs

In classic ER random graph, the edge distribution is Bernoulli. Given a weighted random graph where the edge weight is restricted in $[0,1]$, is there a canonical assumption of the weight distribution in researches? If so, it would be very helpful if you could also help provide some reference.

Comment: The short answer is: no.